# Worst case time to fetch operand from memory

Tags: c, assembly

I am unsure of how to solve this. Can someone please explain the steps I should take as I need to understand this question.

Considering address alignment, what is the worst case time required to fetch 4-byte operand from a memory with a 60 nano second cycle time and a data bus that is 8 bits wide?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What platform architecture? What memory type? What memory  frequency, if applicable? CPU caches? Other circumstances?

Comment: Worst case time would be infinite time.  Worst case, the memory controller catastrophically fails in some way just after you make the request.

Comment: Are you sure it's `8 bits`, not `8 bytes` for the data bus?

Comment: Is there paging or any sort of MMU involved? Something like a TLB miss can cause several fetches from memory (due to walking paging structures) before CPU can convert virtual address into physical address and fetch the data you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no cache or TLB misses hits, your "typical" worst case with a carefully designed processor should be four, single-byte reads at 60ns --> 240ns.  That's probably the expected answer.

To really answer the question, you need to think about perverse cases.

A comment has noted it can take infinite time if the hardware fails, but that's kind of a joke answer.

But it can take a lot longer than you think even if the hardware doesn't fail.

Another commenter has noted that if there is a page map, you can get surprised by page map ("TLB") refills.   A TLB miss to refill page translation slots may require reads of one or "words" (pointers/protection bits) typically of several bytes before the actual data read commences.

Then consider the case of your 4 byte value spanning a virtual page boundary, and at least one of the virtual pages has been pushed out of physical memory to the paging file on disk.  Then the access time is determined by the time to seek/rotate/read/adjust memory map, all of which can take tens of milliseconds (more if the heads have to seek a long distance).

If both pages are pushed to disk, you might face 2 seek times.  Even more delay if the drive has spun down, and has to spin up.

A badly designed OS might trap on page-not-present on the lower address, then page in the first page,  restart the instruction, take a page-not-present fault on the second page, evict the first page to make space for the second page, restart the offending instruction a second time, and then repeat this cycle. Then the access can take forever without a hardware failure. I assume modern OSes lock sequential virtual page pairs to avoid this. (This gets really crazy if you take into account that the instruction body might span page boundaries, and might also not be present in the memory map).

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense. If the data bus is 8 bits wide, then address alignment isn't an issue for operands that are some multiple of bytes long (1 to n), unless you're reading bit fields that span byte boundaries.